# java - MVC design: controller who spins up service threads

Tags: java, multithreading, model-view-controller

I have one controller who has an instance of the view (a javafx app but that shouldn't play a role for this question) and who has a public method `String processInput(String input)` that is called from a button event in the view and the controller puts the returned String in a textfield of its view.

The `processInput(String in)` method creates a new runnable `StringService(String in)` instance on a new thread which does the "model logic" in its `run()` method.

At the moment, the Controller has to wait until the `StringService()` thread has died until it retrieves the results from the service via `StringService.getResult()`.

```
public class Controller
{
    private final View view;

    /*..*/
    public void processInput(final String in)
    {
        StringService service = new StringService(in);
        Thread task = new Thread(service);
        task.start();

        task.join(); // in a try-catch

        /* Controller is now waiting... */

        view.setDisplay(service.getResult());
    }

}
```

It would be nice if the Controller wouldn't need to wait for the `Service` until it can respond again. So as soon as the `Service` thread is finished the Controller gets the results but in the meantime it can do other stuff.

I have thought of making the Controller runnable as well which runs indefinitely and checking in periodic intervals whether there has been a new input from the view or a `Service` has finished. The controller would have to `Queue`s, one for inputs and one for results from the `Service`s, which are checked regularly. Example:

```
public class Controller implements Runnable
{
    /*...*/
    private final int numProcesses = 10;
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numProcesses );
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> inputQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(numProcesses );
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> outputQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(numProcesses);

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            checkInputQueue();  // creates new StringService threads
            checkOutputQueue(); // returns something to view if non-empty
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you even bother creating a `Thread` in the first place? Starting a thread and blocking on `join()` is the same as not starting a thread at all. I think you have a design problem, and you're trying to be too clever for your own good.

Comment: when there are several users then we don't want a user to wait for the controller until it has processed the input of another user. that is, there should be one thread per user. that's why I think there should be a thread pool with the max. number of users and I somehow have to map from user (just a user string) to the executed thread

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you have multiple users, shouldn't they have their own threads? I haven't used JavaFX, but it seems to me you're looking for the wrong solution.

Comment: the solution should be agnostic of the view implementation. be it javafx or a rest api. Yes exactly, each user should have their own StringService threads that are managed by the Controller. I might just have a Map<String, ExecutorService> which assigns each user a thread pool of size 1

Comment: No, each user will have their own thread they use to call `processInput()`. You don't actually need to do anything but call `StringService.run()` in `processInput()`, although you might want to rename things. That's how webapps, rest services etc. work. You might want to read some tutorials before you continue. You're going down the wrong path and fast.